# What (if any) would be a simpler way to structure this middle man thread/object

Tags: c#, multithreading

This my proposed structure for my C# program.

My LIN Comms Object/Thread.

- Reads data from LIN, and fires two events (data received and data
  changed)
- then check to see if there is any in the write queue
- if so it writes then repeats
- if not it repeats

I would like to know if there is another way to structure my Main Logic (Middle Man) Thread/Object. So I can have my events handled/run on the Main Logic Thread with out a task queue and loop?

Or is there some othere preexisting class that I can inherit from that provides this function.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: Nothing, it just seems kinda complicated.

Comment: Sometimes the complexity is justified.  Everything in your current architecture seems like it has a purpose.